# Trying to parse a fairly complex text file

Tags: matlab, text-parsing

I have multiple text file, each is a result of a simulation. The content of the file is as follow:

```
Parameter_1 = value
Parameter_2 = value
.....

Test 1
Min: value
Max: value
Average: value

Test 2
Min: value
Max: value
Average: value
```

Each file contains the same type of parameters with different values, and of course the tests values are different as well.

I need to be able to import this data to Matlab. What I want to do in Matlab is to be able to create charts of parameters (x-axis) and test results. For example, a chart of `Test 1 Min` values when `Parameter_1` changes means selecting n files where only Parameter_1 differs and compare the Test 1 Min results.

Here's my question:  how should I organize that data in my text file to make it easy to import to Matlab? I'm new to Matlab and so I'm don't know what's the best way.

Any ideas that can help me get started would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What is the variability between the text files? More specifically, do all files have the same number of `Parameter_N`s? Do they all have the same number of `Test`s? Do all tests have just 3 values `Min`, `Max`, `Average`?

Comment: Different files has different parameter values and different tests values. I've edited my question.

Comment: you could try an excel or a csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Best way to organize data" is a very contentious question. If you ask 10 people you will get 11 different answers. It often depends on the data and the functionality you have available to you for importing and exporting the data.

That being said, Matlab excels (ha, no pun intended) at importing purely numerical data. If you can organize your file to be composed of only numbers, then a quick 'load', 'dlmread', or 'csvread' command will import them. Including textual data makes things a fair bit more complex.

For example, if you files are very consistent and you could organize the files like this:

```
Param1Value,Param2Value,Param3Value
1,Test1min,test1max,test1average
2,Test2min,test2max,test2average
```

where all the text in the example are simply numerical values (integers or floats), it would be very easy to import into Matlab. You would know the first row contains your parameter values

```
data = csvread('input.csv');
params = data(1,:);
```

And you could pull out quickly the test numbers, min, max, and average values.

```
tests = data(2:end,1);
mins = data(2:end,2);
maxs = data(2:end,3);
avgs = data(2:end,4);
```

But this all hinges on how flexible you are on the output side.

Comment: Text would make it easier to tell what parameter a number represents. Also I have a lot of different text files from different simulations. Wouldn't it be a mess? I'll keep your advice in mind anyway

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing fundamentally wrong with your file. You will need to write a parser. But fear not it's not too hard.

Regexp is very useful for this. I takes a bit reading to get the hang of it - but it's incredible powerful.

I would use code like this:

```
fid = fopen('myfile.txt');
result = {};
result_entry=[];
while 1
    tline = fgetl(fid);
    if ~ischar(tline), break, end

    r = regexp(tline,'^(?<key>\w+)\W*=\W*(?<value>.*?)\W*$','names');
    if ~isempty(r)
    parameter_list.(r.key) = r.value;
    continue
    end

    % does a new entry start?
    r = regexp(tline,'^Test\W+(?<num>\d+)\W*$','names');
    if ~isempty(r)
        result = [result,{result_entry}];
        result_entry = struct('TestNumber',r.num);
        continue
    end

    r = regexp(tline,'^(?<key>\w+)\W*:\W*(?<value>.*?)\W*$','names');
    if ~isempty(r)
        result_entry.(r.key) = r.value;
    end
end
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a lot of effort on your side :) I know regex - I'm only new to Matlab. I use python and can decide the output format - my question is what's a good format? Thanks!

Comment: Well, from my experience most text based formats work great. The built in tools for XML and hdf5 perform very poorly unless you go through Java.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea - analogous to JSON you could make your saves as valid matlab m files. That way you can have all structure features matlab offers an still rather quick reading.