# importing data with a very complex structure into matlab

Tags: matlab, import

i have some data files that i would like to load into matlab. unfortunatly, they have a quite complex structure - at least compared to what i am used to. you should be able to download an old example of this here, https://www.dropbox.com/s/vbh6kl334c5zg1s/fn1_2.out (it opens fine in notepad or wordpad)

it is data files based on synchrotron data where both the raw data, regularized "raw" data and the (indirect) fourier transformed data+fit to data is listed. there are furthermore some statistics from the fourier transformation.

I just need to quote the results from the statistics in my paper, so while it would be nice to plot some of the results, it is not strictly necessary. I need, however, the raw and regularized data together with the fit, and the fourier transformed data.

**My problem**

in the data file, the results from the statistical analysis is shown before the data i need. but the size of the columns from the statistical analysis varies from data file to data file. this means that i cannot just include the statistics in the header unless i manually change the number of header lines for each file i import. i need to analysis groups of 5 data files together and i would at least need to analyze around 30 files this time so i would like to avoid it if possible. in the future i would again need to load this kind of data files - so even if changing the number of headerlines 30 times does not sound bad it would be nice to be able do it automatically

**Possible solution**

both the he raw and regularized data together with the fit as well as the fourier transformed data are preceded by a specific line that tells me that *after this and a blank/empty line, the data begins*

so i though that maybe i could use regular expressions to tell matlab to *ignore everything until you see this specific line, ignore this line and one more, and then import data*

i googled and found this topic where regular expressions are used: [Trying to parse a fairly complex text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988379/trying-to-parse-a-fairly-complex-text-file)

but i am new to regular expressions and the code suggested is a bit complex for me. i can gather that he uses *named capture* but i am not quite sure i understand how he uses it and if i can adopt it to me need. i have checked the official matlab documentation but their examples are somewhat simpler :) (http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#bqm94nz-1)

Sorry for writing such a long post. any suggestions on how to proceed with this problem will be greatly appreciated

/Martin

**EDIT**

the code i have used based on the link in the comment:

```
fileName = 'data.dat';
inputfile = fopen(fileName);

% Ignore all until we see one that just consists of this:
startString = '       R          P(R)      ERROR';

mydata = [];

while 1
 tline = fgetl(inputfile);

 % Break if we hit end of file, or the start marker
 if ~ischar(tline)  ||  strcmp(tline, startString)
    break
 end

 data = sscanf(tline, '%f', 3 );
 mydata(end+1,:) = data;

end
fclose(inputfile);
```

When i run the code i get the error:

```
 Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

 mydata(end+1,:) = data;
```

any suggestions will be greatly appriciated and my apologize for the strange layout/leaving the link in the comment. i am not allowed to include more than two links in a post and i cannot add a new answer yet - both due to me having to low rep :)

Comment: I have found this method of ignoring everything until a specific line: [link](http://wiki.stdout.org/matlabcookbook/File%20IO/Skipping%20lines%20while%20reading%20a%20text%20file/).            I have tried to incorporate the solution and the code is shown in next comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the blocks are separated by at least two new lines you can use that to separate the text into blocks and analyse them individually. Try this code

```
fileH = fopen('fn1_2.out');
content = fscanf(fileH, '%c', inf);
fclose(fileH);

splitstring = regexp(content, '\r\n\r\n', 'split');

blocks = regexp(splitstring, '\d\.\d{4}.*\r\n.*\d\.\d{4}','match');
numericBlocksIdx = find(cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(x), blocks));
numericBlocks = splitstring(numericBlocksIdx);
```

Now the `numericBlocks{1}`, `numericBlocks{2}`, ... contain the tables that you are interested in. Note that for some tables the headers are also included because they are not separated by two new lines. From here you can use functions like [textscan](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html) to read the data into matrices.

Comment: Great! your code works beautifully :)                                 Thanks for the help. i start working on using textscan to extract read the data into matrices

Comment: Glad it worked. Note that the second regular expression assumes that the table has at least two lines of numbers. If that cannot be assumed you should change that to something else.

Comment: I have tried using textscan to read the data from the different blocks. but so far i have unsuccessfull. all i get is empty cell structures. i have two screenshots of that [link1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gh4e3rdtnlptlt1/textscan_probs.png) and [link2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t7s8z4rar697a50/textscan_probsII.png). the last command where i change the name to "numeasd" was just to ensure that the problem is have is not because i have misspelled the cell name. I hope my question/problem is not too stupid :)

Comment: using "textscan(numericBlocks{1,4},'%f');" will actually work in the sence that the data is read. but it is stored in just on array. this means that the x-values are stored on indices 1:3:301, y-values 2:3:302 and Standard error 3:3:303 so i just have to find a method for extract the data from specific indices into a new array - i'm working on that now

Comment: you can use textscan(numericBlocks{1,4},'%f%f%f'); instead. Then the columns will be grouped. Have a look at the examples in the documentation of textscan.

Comment: I tried that and took a screenshot of it - it is shown in the screenshots i linked to above. i just checked again and i still get the empty arrays: >> c = textscan(numericBlocks{1,4}, repmat('%f',3))

c = 

    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]

I guess it is because textscan cannot recognize that the string contains three columns of data.

Comment: type repmat('%f',3) in command-line to see it is different from '%f%f%f'. Either use '%f%f%f' or repmat('%f',1,3)

Comment: Cheers - that worked! i really appreciate you take so much time to help me :)